# Join a cursor or record set in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, database-cursor

I have good experience in sybase and have started looking into oracle in free time.
Most of the sybase procedures that i have worked with have temp tables and it makes sense to join two or more temp tables get a result set.

**Question:
Is there a way to join two or more cursors like a logical table.**

Something like:

```
SELECT c1.id, 
       c2.name 
  FROM cursorEmp c1, 
       CursorDept c2 
 WHERE c1.DeptId = c2.DeptId
```

Comment: What version of Oracle?  IME (oracle 10g), you couldn't join cursors (implicit, explicit or REFCURSORS).  With more information about what the cursors are encapsulating, it's very likely you don't need the cursors (or temp tables) at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot join two cursors, no.

You could, of course, combine the two underlying queries, i.e.

```
SELECT c1.id,
       c2.name
  FROM (SELECT * FROM emp WHERE ename = 'KING') c1,
       (SELECT * FROM dept WHERE dname = 'ACCOUNTING') c2
 WHERE c1.DeptID = c2.DeptID
```

In Oracle, since readers do not block writers (and vice versa), it is very rarely necessary to use temporary tables.  You would normally just query the underlying tables using views as appropriate to provide appropriate levels of abstraction.

Comment: Thank you Justin, But what do you mean by "Readers do not block writers" ? When a select is executed wont the record be locked in read(shared) mode , denying exclusive lock to the writer process.

Comment: SELECT won't take any lock (unless you do a SELECT ...FOR UPDATE). To stop a select reading uncommitted changes, it uses something like a timestamp (an SCN) and looks for a historic copy of the row from before the time it was locked.

Comment: Thank you Gary, I did some reading on the subject and looks like shared locking is more a sybase feature. I have more questions now, But let me search before I ask the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does have its own version of temporary tables (permanent structures with temporary data stored for the duration of either a transaction or a session) - you could consider using those, although (as Justin suggested) you could also combine the two underlying queries.

Comment: Thank you Mark, I am aware of Global Temporary Tables. But I feel they might clutter the database. What is your thought on it ? I have more questions on views now, time for me to read more.

Comment: I haven't used Oracle temporary tables much, but then I haven't worked in an environment where I needed to convert between SQLServer procedures that made extensive use of temporary tables, and Oracle procedures. I have occasionally made use of them where there was no practical alternative, but more frequently I have run combined queries, with hinting as necessary.